# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет, поискав тут информацию ничего толком не нашел, поэтому не судите за вопросик
При добавлении скриншота вылетает вот такая ошибка Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in Помогите поправить или подскажите как правильно должно быть

Вот собственно код

Вот эта строка : `$type = array_pop(explode('.',$src_s));`

````
list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($src_s);
if($type=='png') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefrompng($src_s);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);
}
if($type=='gif') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefromgif($src_s);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);}
if($type=='jpeg') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_s);}
if($type=='jpg') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_s);}
if($type=='PNG') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefrompng($src_s);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);
}
if($type=='GIF') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefromgif($src_s);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);}
if($type=='JPEG') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_s);}
if($type=='JPG') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_s);}
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);
$pos_x = $owidth - $w_width-5;
$pos_y = $oheight - $w_height-5;
imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
if($type=='png') {unlink($src_s); imagepng($im, $src_s, 9);}
//if($type=='gif') {unlink($src_s); imagegif($im, $src_s, 60);}
if($type=='jpeg') {unlink($src_s); imagejpeg($im, $src_s, 60);}
if($type=='jpg') {unlink($src_s); imagejpeg($im, $src_s, 60);}
if($type=='PNG') {unlink($src_s); imagepng($im, $src_s, 9);}
//if($type=='GIF') {unlink($src_s); imagegif($im, $src_s, 60);}
if($type=='JPEG') {unlink($src_s); imagejpeg($im, $src_s, 60);}
if($type=='JPG') {unlink($src_s); imagejpeg($im, $src_s, 60);}
imagedestroy($im);
mysqli_query($connect_db, "INSERT INTO `".DB_PREFIX."_es_i` (m,img) VALUES ('$id','$srcs')");
mysqli_query($connect_db, "UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."_users SET rat=rat+0.02 WHERE uid='$u_id' LIMIT 1");
exit('1');
} else {
exit('3');
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Значит что в `array_pop()` в качестве параметра может быть передана только переменная

Вы же пытаетесь в нее скормить значение непосредственно из результатов выполнения `explode('.',$src_s)`

В вашем случае нужно все разделить на два этапа

1. сначала сохранить результаты `explode('.',$src_s)` в переменную
2. передать эту переменную в `array_pop()`

```
$parts = explode('.',$src_s);
$type = array_pop($parts);
```

и так уже будет работать

**рабочий пример.**

```
$src_s = "192.168.2.145";
$parts = explode('.',$src_s);
$type = array_pop($parts);
echo "$type\n";
```

**output**

```
145
```

Comment: А я тут все пересмотрел перепробовал по всякому а тут вот так)) спасибо большое. Заработала загрузка и страница стала обновляться после добавления скриншота

Comment: @Денис, отлично! Рад что все заработало) постите еще вопросы если будут